# BigQuery: update a column if a record exists in other tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

A client has multiple rows in both table1 and table2.  I want to update a boolean, table1.email_flag, to true for every row for a client, if that client has one or more rows with email_flag=true in either table1 or table2 (or both).

This SQL does it:

```
update table1 a
  set email_flag = true
  from
    (select client_id
    from table1
    where email_flag = true
    UNION DISTINCT
    select client_id
    from table2
    where email_flag = true) b
  where a.client_id = b.client_id;
```

But I need to rewrite it without the UNION.

Some sample data:

Table1:

| rownum | client_id | email_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client1 | false |
| 2 | Client1 | true |
| 3 | Client1 | false |
| 4 | Client2 | false |
| 5 | Client2 | false |
| 6 | Client3 | true |
| 7 | Client3 | true |
| 8 | Client3 | false |
| 9 | Client4 | false |
| 10 | Client4 | false |

Table2:

| rownum | client_id | email_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client1 | false |
| 2 | Client1 | false |
| 3 | Client1 | false |
| 4 | Client1 | false |
| 5 | Client2 | false |
| 6 | Client2 | false |
| 7 | Client3 | true |
| 8 | Client3 | false |
| 9 | Client3 | false |
| 10 | Client4 | false |
| 11 | Client4 | true |

Desired outcome for Table1:

| rownum | client_id | email_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client1 | true |
| 2 | Client1 | true |
| 3 | Client1 | true |
| 4 | Client2 | false |
| 5 | Client2 | false |
| 6 | Client3 | true |
| 7 | Client3 | true |
| 8 | Client3 | true |
| 9 | Client4 | true |
| 10 | Client4 | true |

- All of Client1's rows will be True because it has a True row in
  Table1
- All of Client2's rows will be False because it doesn't have
  any True records in either table
- All of Client3's rows will be True
  because it has True rows in both tables
- All of Client4's rows will be
  True because it has a True row in Table2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `EXISTS` expressions, that check from both tables if there's at least one email_flag set to true for the specific client.

```
UPDATE table1 a
SET email_flag = true
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 b WHERE email_flag='true' AND a.client_id = b.client_id) 
   OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 b WHERE email_flag='true' AND a.client_id = b.client_id);
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks so much for your response.  But I think I do need to check table1 too...  A client will have several rows in table1, some of which might have email_flag=true.  I need to update all of the rows for that client to true if any of the table1 rows are true - and/or if any of the table2 rows are true.

Comment: Because email_flag might be set to true for some of the rows for a client but not for all of them.  And I need to update the table so that all of the client's rows are true.

Comment: I think I'm explaining myself very badly - apologies.  I've edited the original question with some more info...

Comment: By the way...  the SQL I posted works - but I've been told to rewrite it without the UNION.

Comment: Oh ok...  done now

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!  That's a much more elegant solution.  Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider marking your post as answered if this answer helped you.